# Declare enum class refering to another enum class

Tags: c++, enums

Assuming I have a class :

```c
Class Core {
    
  public :
        enum class Region { EU, US, JP};
}
      
Class System {

  private :
      
      Core _core;

  public :
  
      void setCoreRegion(Core::Region region) { _core.setRegion(region); }
}
```

I don't want the users of the class System have to know Core Class and have to use Core:: XX to set the region. I don't want expose core class to user space.
I don't want to do another equivalent enum class in class System

In summary I would like to expose to the user of class System the enumeration like it was on system class

```c
system.setRegion(System::Region EU);
```

Are there any tips for that?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know one could capitalise the `class` keyword in C++? Next time please include the programming language in the tags.

Comment: Is an error in my message i will correct it. Thank you.

Comment: You know `Core::Region` is private, right? Could you post actual code that might conceivably compile?

Comment: Srry it was for the example and i don't find how to correct my post ...

Comment: @vmicka Just click the [edit] button below the post

Comment: C++ keywords are case-sensitive and all-lowercase, so it should be `class` (unless you `#define Class class`, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a solution :

```
Class System {

    public :
    
        using Region = Core::Region;
   }
```

When i am on user class i can use System::Region.

It seems to be correct.

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution in modern C++. See https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rt-using